# Retrieve the value of a XML attribute in VBS

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, xml-attribute

```
<Requirement Description="description" Operation="Configure">
   <Action ID="1000" Name="Split">
     <Contract>
       <Parameter Name="Version">4</Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="DefaultServer">192.168.00.</Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="DefaultUser">administrator</Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="DefaultPassword">password</Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="DefaultDomain">192.168.00.00</Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="Split">1</Parameter>
     </Contract>
   </Action>
</Requirement>
```

From the above XML document my aim is to replace the IP address for both the attributes default server and default domain from a VBScript.

```
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.async = False
objXMLDoc.load(XMLFullPath) 
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes("//Parameter")

NodeList(i).nodeName
```

Give name as Parameter and `NodeList(i).Text` gives me values like 4, IP address, administrator and others. But I am not able to get the attribute name so that I can directly change the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, you can use the [`getAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to access an attribute's value:

```
NodeList(i).getAttribute("Name")
```

---

You can also add a predicate to the XPath expression in your `SelectNodes` call to retrieve only the desired elements:

```
Set NodeList = objXMLDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes("//Parameter[@Name = 'DefaultServer' or @Name = 'DefaultDomain']")
```

This way, you don't have to retrieve and loop through the Parameter nodes that you're not interested in.

Comment: getAttribute("") was something I was missing on one of my scripts. thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

A bit rusty, but I think you can use this to retrieve the nodevalue by nodename:

```
Function getTag(nList, nName)
    Dim i
    i = 0
    Do while i < nList.childNodes.length
        if (nList.childNodes(i).nodeName = nName) then
            getTag = nList.childNodes(i).childNodes(0).text
            Exit Function
        end if
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

And to set it, probably

```
Sub setTag(nList, nName, val)
    Dim i
    i = 0
    Do while i < nList.childNodes.length
        if (nList.childNodes(i).nodeName = nName) then
            nList.childNodes(i).childNodes(0).text = val
            Exit Sub
        end if
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: set obj = NodeList(i).attributes  this gives all the values of the attributes. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Ohhh... banging my head against the desk now that I didn't read your question more carefully.